# how to display multiple images in php from database using slideshow

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4

I have images that have been uploaded from a database **but I want the images to be in a slideshow** 
my code :

```
while ($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($res2))
        {
          $image=$row2 ['img_name'];
          echo'
                  <td>
                  <img src="../photo/'.$image.'" width="360" height="150">
                  </td>';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <div class="carousel-inner">
     while ($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($res2))
       {
         $image=$row2 ['img_name'];
         echo'                    
          <div class="carousel-item active">         
                <img src="../photo/'.$image.'" width="360" height="150">                   
           </div> ';
         }
  </div>
</div>
```